# UBUNTU 17.04 install openface and anaconda3

Tags: ubuntu

I 'm new to Linux, I want install openface using Anaconda 5.0.0 linux, Python 3.6 on Ubuntu.
I 've followed all the steps listed here: https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/docs/setup.md
using Anaconda instead of miniconda in step 1.

after installation run 'jupyter notebook', then if run a .py file containing the line "import openface" it fails:

no module named openface

If open a terminal, go to /openface and run a .py file containing the line "import cv2" it fails:

no module named cv2  (under jupyter notebook 'import cv2' works fine).
Can anyone explain to me how can I set those modules visible, openface in 'jupyter notebook' and cv2 in openface?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Move cv2.so from *dist-packages* to *site-packages* for removing the *"no module named cv2"* error.
And it seems that you haven't run the setup.py file
Go to Terminal:

cd /home/*your_username*/openface

Then run this command: python setup.py install